# Clojure clojure.lang.LazySeq errors

Tags: clojure, lazy-sequences

I seem to have nasty problem with clojure I/O (or typesystem). The point is that this function, which I expect to consume collection of collections of strings and numbers or strings, and returns dictionary of strings associated with numbers, like

```
(costlist '( '("Milk" 4) '("Bread" 2) '("Milk")))
```

giving

`{"Milk" 4, "Bread" 2 }`

Defined by

```
(defn costlist [lst]
    ;returns list of costs and appropriate names
          (let  [snds (filter (fn [x] (not (identical? nil x))) (seconds lst))]
          (zipmap 
                   (firsts (take (count snds) (firsts lst))) 
                   (snds  lst))))
```

when consuming lists of type clojure.lang.PersistentList (which I converted from clojure.lang.LazySeq) throws error message

```
clojure.lang.LazySeq cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn
```

Which only confuses me, as any of its arguments don't seem to be LazySeq to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `snds` is the lazy seq, so `(snds  lst)` throws an error. `filter` always returns a lazy seq.

Your function also is too complicated. Try to make it simpler:

```
(defn costlist [lst]
  (zipmap (map first lst)
          (remove nil? (map second lst))))
```

Now you can do what you want:

```
(costlist (list '("Milk" 4) '("Bread" 2) '("Milk")))
```

I'm using `list` because `quote` prevents evaluation of an expression ([see ToBeReplaced's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082070/clojure-clojure-lang-lazyseq-errors/18082306#18082306)):

```
=> '( '("Milk" 4) '("Bread" 2) '("Milk"))
((quote ("Milk" 4)) (quote ("Bread" 2)) (quote ("Milk")))
```

So, you should avoid using `quote` for building lists.

Your solution also suggests that `nil` values may occur only at the end of the list. You can easily fix it:

```
(defn costlist [lst]
  (->>  (filter (comp #{2} count) lst)
        (map vec)
        (into {})))
```

So, now

```
(costlist (list '("Milk" 4) '("Milk") '("Bread" 2)))
```

will work too.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to give you a precise answer because you are also using some of your own functions (seconds and firsts).  However, you should consider whether you want `costlist` to be the quoted form you give above.

The above is equivalent to:

```
((quote ("Milk" 4)) (quote ("Bread" 2)) (quote ("Milk")))
```

I think you want something more like:

```
(list '("Milk" 4) '("Bread" 2) '("Milk"))
```

In your example, the outermost quote is causing the inner quotes to be quoted!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `'` inside `'()`. You don't want to `quote` `'` to get `quote`.
Given you write your list as:

```
'(("Milk" 4)("Bread" 2)("Milk"))
```

The most elegant probably be:

```
(def costlist (comp (partial into {}) 
                    (partial map vec) 
                    (partial filter second))
```

similar to

```
(def costlist #(into {} (map vec (filter second %))))
```

Unfortunately this will create two lazy-seqs and one would be nicer for performance.
You could `(use '(clojure.core [reducers :as r])` and compose yourself a cool reducing function:

```
(def r-fn (comp (r/map vec) (r/filter second)))
```

Which leaves you to

```
(def costlist #(into {} (r-fn %)))
```

Thanks to `into` using `reduce conj` your list elements will only be allocated once.

Since order does not matter for hash-maps, you can also user `r/fold`. Then your list will be filtered and the elements converted to vectors in parallel (If your list has more than 512 elements).

```
(def constlist #(r/fold (r/monoid conj hash-map) (r-fn %)))
```

Depending on the size of the collection, reducers may be a bit too heavy. For a small size like the one from your example I recommend to write your own reducing function:

```
(def costlist #(reduce (fn [acc [k v]]
                         (if v
                           (assoc acc k v)
                           acc)) {} %)
```